# React native bottom-tabs bottom navigation bar has ugly white line on top

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-navigation-bottom-tab

So I am making a bottom navigation bar for a react native app, and the bottom navigation bar has a white line on top as so:
[image: Bottom navigation bar image]
I made an expo snack that reproduces this, I hope someone can find a solution :))

[The expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@mariusdarius/moving-between-screens-%7C-react-navigation)

I tried tweaking the positioning and playing around with style props, but the white line is seemingly always there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [borderTopWidth](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#bordertopwidth) to zero.

```js
screenOptions={{
  tabBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#272929',
...
    borderTopWidth: 0,
  },
}}
```